# Diagram for spotting distributions, like "contradicting" results

Tags: distributions, scatterplot, categorical-data, ratio

Let's say we have two results that are related to each other:

- Result 1 was a questionnaire about food and had two options "I dislike Cake" and "I like Cake". The result is displayed as a ratio: "1:3" where 1 is the group that dislike cake and 3 is the group that likes Cake. Similarily, the ratio was 3:20 when asked if they disliked or liked Carrots.
- Result 2 was a questionnaire that was analysed by picking the most common answer. 80% dislike the flavor of Cake and 90% said they liked the flavor of Carrots.

Now as you might see, this is a bit weird. While the result for Carrot is pretty logical; they like carrots & the flavor, the result for Cake is weird. They like cake but dislike the flavor!

**I would like to make a nice way of presenting these kind of results in some diagram of sort. That way, if we have 30 food items, the reader can easily spot such contradicting results.** For example, a scatterplot would group a whole bunch of food items together and then Cake with its "contradicting" result would be placed outside that cluster and so the reader would easily spot that "aha, Cake looks pretty odd, why is it over there?". Unfortunately  I have a hard time realizing how that could be presented since Result 1 is using ratios.

Comment: You can turn the ratio in Result 1 into a percentage, and then plot the ratio of the percentages (or the differences) in a dot plot.